# Regex : capturing group?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I was wondering if it is possible to use capturing groups with MongoDB.

For example, assuming I have a collection of users with only their full name, and I want to get their first and last name.

Here's what I was thinking of using capturing groups :

```
bulk.find( { full_name: /<first_name>(.*) <last_name>(.*)/i } ).upsert().replaceOne(
   {
     first_name: <first_name>,
     last_name: <last_name>
   }
);
bulk.execute();
```

Is it possible using only MongoDB ? How would you do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using javascript :

doc here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Example :

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(e) {
var fullName = e.full_name
e.firstname = full_name.substring(\*something*\)
e.lastname = full_name.substring(\*something*\)
db.collection.save(e);
 });
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks! I didn't even know you could put Javascript :o)

Comment: This isn't just using MongoDB. `db.collection.find()` is returning a (Javascript) cursor object over all documents. The `forEach` method on the cursor applies the function to each result, which makes one call to the database. So if your collection has 1234567 documents, the above code makes at least 1234568 calls to the database. Capture groups aren't available in MongoDB queries as of (2.6), so you'll have to do something like the answer, possibly with batching.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @wdberkeley 
And you're right, the performance is not good at all!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB version 4.2 (released in August 2019) provides the
[regexFind operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/). From the documentation:

> Provides regular expression (regex) pattern matching capability in
> aggregation expressions. If a match is found, returns a document that
> contains information on the first match... If your regex pattern
> contains capture groups and the pattern finds a match in the input,
> the captures array in the results corresponds to the groups captured
> by the matching string.

Syntax:

```
{ $regexFind: { input: <expression> , regex: <expression>, options: <expression> } }
```

E.g. (I didn't verify your regex does what you want)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      names: {
        $regexFind: { input: "$phone", regex: /(.*) (.*)/i }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and the output would be

```
{ "names" : { "match" : "John Doe", "idx" : 0, "captures" : [ "John", "Doe" ] } }
```